# SQL nested select statement;

Tags: sql, db2

I need to make a new table based on this datatable schema. 
I am not exactly sure if i can do that using nested sql select statements or else.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can start by writing a SQL statement.  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes i have tried multiple times. I am dealing with DB2 IBM AS400 server queries and sometimes it gets messy. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, (select ColE from table where colA=120) ColE
from table
where colA = 122
```

Just using a nested select for colE and giving an Alias to the column.

Comment: This will fail if `colA` can take the value `120` in more than one row.  Admittedly, the OP doesn't say what to do in this case.

Comment: I suppose he is working this way, because ColA is PK, but if not, he can always add: AND ROWNUM = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the condition to find ColE if there are multiple values in ColA. I'm assuming (based from your table) you want the smallest value?

```
select min(ColE) 
from table
where ColA=120
group by ColA;
```

Now using the above you can create a nested select

```
select ColC, ColB, ColC,ColD , minColE
from table, (
    select min(ColE) as minColE
    from table
    where ColA=120
    group by ColA
) as TblA
where ColA=122;
```